# Custom embed the data source variable in the connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection

how do I custom call the data source of a connection string, the existing connection string is stored in the web.config file. I am using Oledb to connect to an Excel sheet uploaded to the server.

I have got my connection strings in the web.config file. Earlier, I was hard-coding the entire string including the data source location in the web.config file.

```
//this one works
<add name="testexcel1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\usethis\WebApplication1\Uploaded Files\weekly output target.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0'"/>

//I would like to specify the data source parameter in my code behind file.
   <add name="testexcel" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"/>

//this is what I am trying to do, but it just does not work, the string gets concatenated wrongly.
string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded Files/" + filename);
builder.Provider = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testexcel1"].ConnectionString;
        builder.DataSource = accept_filelocation;

//This is finally working
string connectionStringProvider =
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testexcel1"].ConnectionString;

        string dataSource = accept_filelocation;

        string connectionString = String.Format(connectionStringProvider, dataSource);



        OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to read the connection string format (including {0}) from configuration and apply it to a given data source:

```
string connectionStringFormat = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testexcel1"].ConnectionString;

string dataSource = Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded Files/" + filename);

string connectionString = String.Format(connectionStringFormat, dataSource);
var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I was of the understanding that I needed to include some properties to the connectingString, like using the builder and the provider. Learnt something new today. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Cally You certainly don't want to parse the connection string when `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` does that for you ;)

Comment: Noted. I am updating my earlier post with the one that I have modified now.